# Flash builder / Flex mobile tabbar without container and with custom functions

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4.5

I am developing app in Flash builder 4.6 as Flex Mobile project.

I have 4 different views being shown inside ViewNavigatorApplication. One of the views need to have tabbed menu bar at the bottom of the screen. That tabbar needs to control sorting method of list element. I could use custom made tabbar but I really want the same look and feel as the one that comes with TabbedViewNavigator. What are my options for doing such tabbar?

Should I use TabbedViewNavigator as application container and start showing/hiding the tabbar as necessary for every view (then I must overwrite the tab buttons handler so that it wont change the view but do the sorting instead) or is there a way to extract the tabbar from TabbedViewNavigator and simply add it to one of the views?